# difference between exporting and sourcing an env var?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In a shell script, what is the difference between the following?

```
export $(cat .env)
```

and

```
source .env
```

where `.env` is the name of a file with a key=value specified on each line. I'm not insterested in performance/speed benchmarks, only actual functionality/features. For context, I'm trying to make use of a docker-compose env file in supporting scripts.

Comment: The variable is only exported in the first case. This means that only in this case the variable with its value is available to the environment of a called program and the program can access its value.

Comment: It would be much safer to use `set -a` prior to `source` than relying on the unquoted command substitution to not perform any word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Answer (score -1):

There's no difference from script perspective but the export option will avoid adding `source .env` to every script.
So you could export the variables before running any script and also would help to have a single editing point.

Comment: There is a very big difference between the two, due to the unquoted command substitution.